# How to store List<string> with checkboxes in Db with Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor-pages

I'm quite new with Asp.net

Trying to learn, by doing small projects.

I have issue (I'm stuck) where i want to store multiple values (provided by checkboxes) into single database table field. but can't get around how to correctly do it.

Class where I want to save data

```
public class Supplier
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string SupplierName { get; set; }
        public string SupplierAddress { get; set; } 
        public string SupplierOrigin { get; set; }
        public string SupplierGroup { get; set; }
        public  string FustTypeList { get; set; }
    }
```

Class which one I want to save

```
 public class FustType
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string FustTypeName { get; set; }
        public string? Comment { get; set; } = "N/A";
        public bool IsChecked { get;set; }
    }
```

Controller (methods related with form and view)

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSupplier()
        {

            List<CheckBoxModel> checkBoxModels = new List<CheckBoxModel>();
            List<string> fustTypeList = new();
            await applicationDbContext.FustTypes.ForEachAsync(item => { fustTypeList.Add(item.FustTypeName); });
            int fustTypes = 0;
            await applicationDbContext.FustTypes.ForEachAsync(item =>
            {
                checkBoxModels.Add(
                        new CheckBoxModel()
                        {
                            Id= fustTypes+1,
                            CheckoxName=item.FustTypeName,
                            IsChecked=false
                        });
            });

            ViewBag.FustTypes = fustTypeList;
            ViewBag.CheckBoxModels = checkBoxModels;
            List<string> originList = new();
            await applicationDbContext.Origins.ForEachAsync(item => { originList.Add(item.OriginName); });
            ViewBag.Origins = originList;
            List<string> groupList = new();
            await applicationDbContext.Groups.ForEachAsync(item => { groupList.Add(item.GroupName); });
            ViewBag.Groups = groupList;

            return View();
        }

[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Add(Supplier addSupplierRequest, string Save, List<CheckBoxModel> checkboxModelList)
        {
            if (Save != null)
            {
                var supplier = new Supplier()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    SupplierName = addSupplierRequest.SupplierName,
                    SupplierAddress = addSupplierRequest.SupplierAddress,
                    FustTypeList = addSupplierRequest.FustTypeList,
                    SupplierGroup = addSupplierRequest.SupplierGroup,
                    SupplierOrigin = addSupplierRequest.SupplierOrigin
                };
                await applicationDbContext.Suppliers.AddAsync(supplier);
                await applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();


                TempData["result"] = "Success";
                TempData["action"] = "Supplier Creation";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["result"] = "Fail";
                TempData["action"] = "Supplier Creation";
                return RedirectToAction("CreateSupplier");
            }
        }
```

View file where form is being submited (original view is biggere with different information, but to keep it compact I removed it, as form is submiting other data correctly and stores data in database)

```
@model FustWebApp.Models.Domain.Supplier
@using FustWebApp.Models;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create Supplier";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";

    var checkboxList = (List<CheckBoxModel>)ViewBag.CheckBoxModels;

}
@if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <div class="@ViewBag.Style  text-sm-center mb-1 py-1"><h4>@ViewBag.Message</h4></div>
}

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Add", "Suppliers", HttpMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row mb-2">
            
            @for (int i=0;i<@checkboxList.Count();i++)
            {
                 @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.FustTypeList,htmlAttributes:new{@class ="col-form-label col-sm-2"})
                <div class="col-auto">

                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.FustTypeList)

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FustTypeList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                </div>
            
            }

        </div>

    </div>

}
```

Checkboxes are generated based on already saved data in different Database table.
Idea is that based on what what checkbox is "checked" it's being added to list List with FustTypeName
I'm stuck in part

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.FustTypeList)
```

as my list should contain strings, but output from checkbox is Boolean

Is there better option how to store multiple "checkbox" values into single database field?

I tried to store checkbox outputs in single string, but didn't work out as expected. as I couldn't figure out how to pass back to controler selected options. Tried

```
<Input type="checkbox" name="Checked" value="CheckboxName"/>
```

and in controller ir got

```
List<string>Checked{get;set;}
```

which one should be storing all values, but it was always empty field on form submit

Comment: Please remove whitespace from the code blocks and format the indents properly. That said, you should save the fust types as a collection of `FustType`s in `Supplier`, i.e. a 1:n relationship with matching tables and relationships in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done different approach and now are able to store names of item in database field as single string by joining them with seperator ','

In View I changed to below

```
<div class="row mb-2">
        
        @for (int i=0;i<@checkboxList.Count();i++)
        {
            
            <div class="col-auto">

                <input name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="@checkboxList[i].CheckBoxName" /> @checkboxList[i].CheckBoxName<br />
                

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FustTypeList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


            </div>
        
        }

    </div>
```

Controller:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public List<string> AreChecked { get; set; }
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(Supplier addSupplierRequest, string Save, List<string> AreChecked)
    {

        if (Save != null)
        {

            string fustTypeList = string.Join(",", AreChecked);

            var supplier = new Supplier()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                SupplierName = addSupplierRequest.SupplierName,
                SupplierAddress = addSupplierRequest.SupplierAddress,
                FustTypeList = fustTypeList,
                SupplierGroup = addSupplierRequest.SupplierGroup,
                SupplierOrigin = addSupplierRequest.SupplierOrigin
            };
```

And by viewing entered values to re-generate which checkboxes were selected in View I process them as:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < checkboxList.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="col-auto">
                @if (Model.FustTypeList.Split(',').Contains(checkboxList[i].CheckBoxName))
                {
                    <input name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
                    @checkboxList[i].CheckBoxName

                    <br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FustTypeList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                }
                else
                {
                    <input name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="@checkboxList[i].CheckBoxName" />
                    @checkboxList[i].CheckBoxName

                    <br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FustTypeList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                }
            </div>
        }
```

Not sure if this is best approach, but it does the job.
I'm able to store multiple selection in single string and regenerate values back in view.

Still learning Asp.net and Entity Framework, so I'm not quite yet there with relations